# Play With UIImageView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

i have 3*3 pieces of images from one image(By Croping) but how to manage move of those imageView for that i have to declare  different objects of all of them or any other way is their... it is possible to manage these much images using array.... Please help buddy

We Can do thi by array of object...?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"3.jpg"];

for(int i = 0;i < 3;i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 3 ; j++)

    [self SetImagePeces:i :j];

}
    [super viewDidLoad];
}


-(void) SetImagePeces:(int)col:(int)row
{

UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"3.jpg"];

img1 = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
img1.frame = CGRectMake(0 + 235 * col, 0 + 235 * row, 233, 233);
img1.tag = row;

img1.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

CGRect clippedRect = CGRectMake(0 + 233 * col,700 - 233 * row, 233, 233);

UIImage *imgV = [self imageByCropping:img toRect:clippedRect];

img1.image = imgV;

[self.view addSubview:img1];
[img1 release];


}
```

UPDATE ::

Still now i experiment on 700 * 700 size image but how to bound any size of image in our size..

** Touch Event :: **

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
   if (touch.view == img2) {

           if (c2 == 0) {
                   tempImg = img2.image;
                   [flag replaceObjectAtIndex:1 withObject:@"1"];
                   c2++;
           }
           else {
                   for(int j=0;j<9;j++)
                   {
                           if(j==1)
                                   {[flag replaceObjectAtIndex:j withObject:@"0"];}
                           else
                           {
                                   int a=[[flag objectAtIndex:j]integerValue];
                           if (a==1) {
                                   img3.image=img2.image;
                                   [flag replaceObjectAtIndex:j withObject:@"0"];
                           }
                           }
                   }
                   img2.image = tempImg;
                   c2 = 0;
           }
   }
   if (touch.view == img3) {

           if (c2 == 0) {
                   tempImg = img3.image;
                   [flag replaceObjectAtIndex:2 withObject:@"1"];
                   c2++;
           }
           else {
                   for(int j=0;j<9;j++)
                   {
                           if(j==2)
                           {[flag replaceObjectAtIndex:j withObject:@"0"];}
                           else
                           {
                           int a=[[flag objectAtIndex:j]integerValue];
                           if (a==1) {
                                   img2.image=img3.image;
                                   [flag replaceObjectAtIndex:j withObject:@"0"];
                           }
                           }
                   }
                   img3.image = tempImg;
                   c2 = 0;
           }
   }


}
```

Here i swap image on touch began method so only implement for 2 images but it is too much difficult to mange for more images

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will use NSMutableDictionary to manage those objects. You can define the key of dictionary as following. Then, you can access the desired image with row and column numbers.

```
- (NSString *)keyForRow:(int)row col:(int)col {
   return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d_%d", row, col];
}
```

**UPDATE**

NSMutableDictionary *myImageDict = ...; ///< a dict to manage UIImageView.

```
- (void)setImageView:(UIImageView *)image row:(int)row col:(int)col
   {
       [myImageDict setObject:image forKey:[self keyForRow:row col:col]];
   }

- (UIImageView *)imageWithRow:(int)row col:(int)col
{
    return [myImageDict objectForKey:[self keyForRow:row col:col]];
}
```

Then, you can manage UIImageView with row and column number by NSMutableDictionary.

About how to move those UIImageView, you can use UIGestureRecognizer to monitor the touch event on the UIImageView. By dealing with those touch events , especially touchedMoved:withEvent:, and modifying the center of UIImageView, you can move those UIImagesView as desired.

Comment: i add my code above pls... give me suggestion... i have to randomly set image than by touch rearrange it...

Comment: thank you buddy i try this one, up till now i use separate  UIImageview object and use touch event. let`s see may be it`s usefull to me...

Answer (score 1):

you need to take multiple uiimageview objects and on touchmove move the center of touched imageview.

Comment: ya buddy i do exactly same way but here i concern only 3 * 3 (9 imageView obj) but when matrix size increse at that time it difficult to manage this much of object and memory manegment of it too... , i also add my Touch event Code see that..